# How to pull the count of occurences from 2 SQL tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, left-join

I am using python on a SQlite3 DB i created. I have the DB created and currently just using command line to try and get the sql statement correct.

I have 2 tables.

```
Table 1 - users
user_id, name, message_count

Table 2 - messages
id, date, message, user_id
```

When I setup table two, I added this statement in the creation of my messages table, but I have no clue what, if anything, it does:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
```

What I am trying to do is return a list containing the name and message count during 2020.  I have used this statement to get the TOTAL number of posts in 2020, and it works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE substr(date,1,4)='2020';
```

But I am struggling with figuring out if I should Join the tables, or if there is a way to pull just the info I need.  The statement I want would look something like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM users JOIN messages ON messages.user_id = users.user_id WHERE substr(date,1,4)='2020';
```

Comment: When you have data from multiple tables that you need in the result set, then `join` is usually the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from messages m 
        where m.user_id = u.user_id and m.date >= '2020-01-01' and m.date < '2021-01-01'
    ) as cnt_messages
from users u
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `messages(user_id, date)`.
You could also `join` and aggregate. If you want to allow users that have no messages, a `left join` is a appropriate:

```
select u.name, count(m.user_id) as cnt_messages
from users u
left join messages m 
    on m.user_id = u.user_id and m.date >= '2020-01-01' and m.date < '2021-01-01'
group by u.user_id, u.name
```

Note that it is more efficient to filter the `date` column against literal dates than applying a function on it (which precludes the use of an index).

Comment: Where are you getting the u.* from? Or are you creating that in this query?

Comment: @Lzypenguin: the `from` clause defines `u` as an alias for table `users`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I just added order by count(m.user_id) desc; to your second edit and it works PERFECTLY!!!!! Thank you so much!!! And the sorting by date work much much better.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a GROUP BY clause to group by user:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, COUNT(*) AS counter 
FROM users u JOIN messages m
ON m.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE substr(m.date,1,4)='2020'
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name
```

Comment: This also works perfectly.  I just removed the u.user_id because it was not needed, and added order by count(*) desc; and it gave me the output I needed. THANK you for your help!